# Implementing arrays using linked lists (and vice versa)

Tags: arrays, linked-list

After learning about arrays and linked lists in class, I'm curious about whether arrays can be used to create linked lists and vice versa.

1. To create a linked list using an array, could I store the first value of the linked list at index 0 of the array, the pointer to the next node at index 1 of the array, and so on? I guess I'm confused because the "pointer to next" seems redundant, given that we know that the index storing the value of the next node will always be: index of value of current node + 2.
2. I don't think it's possible to create an array using a linked list, because an array involves continuous memory, but a linked list can have nodes stored in different parts of computer memory. Is there some way to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a linked list in an array, but only in the sense that you have an ordered list. As you say, you do not need pointers as you know the order (it's explicit in the array ordering). The main differences for choosing between an array or linked list are:

- Arrays are "static" in that items are fixed in their elements. You can't mremove an element and have the array automatically shuffle the following elements down. Of course you can bypass "empty" elements in your iteration it this requires specific logic. With a linked list, if you remove an element, it's gone. With an array, you have to shuffle all subsequent elements down.
- As such, linked lists are often used where insertion/ deletion of elements is the most common activity. Arrays are most often used with access is required (as faster as directly accessed [by index]).
- Another area where you may see benefits of linked lists over arrays is in sorting (where sorting is required or frequent). The reason for this being that linked list sorts require only pointer manipulation whereas aray sorting requires swapping and shuffling. That said, many sorting algorithms create new arrays anyway (merge-sort is typical) which reduces this overhead (though requires the same memory again for the sorted array).
- You can mix your metaphors somewhat if, for example, you enable your linked list to be marked "read-only". That is, you could create an array of pointers to each node in your linked list. that way, you can have indexed access to your linked-list. The array becomes outdated (in the way described above) once elements are added or removed from your linked list (hence the read-only aspect).

So, to answer your specific questions:

1) There's no value in doing this - as per the details above

2) You haven't really provided enough information to answer the question of contiguous memory allocation. It depends on a lot: OS, architecture, compiler implementation. You haven't even mentioned the programming language. In short though, choosing between a linked list and array has little to do with contiguous memory allocation and more to do with usage. For instance, the java `LinkedList` class and `ArrayList` class both represent a `List` implementation but are specialised based on usage patterns. It is expected that `LinkedList` performs better for "lists" expecting high-modification (although in tests done a few years ago this proved to be negligible - I'm not sure of the state in the latest versions of java).

Also, you wouldn't typically "create an array with a linked list" or vice versa. They're both abstract data structures used in building larger components. They represent a list of something in a wider context (e.g. a department has a list of employees). Each datatype just has usage benefits. Similarly, you might use a set, queue, stack, etc. It depends on your usage needs.

I really hope I haven't confused you further!

Answer (score 1):

The array based linked list is generally defined in a 2-dimentional array, something like :

[image]

Benefit: The list will only take up to a specific amount of memory that is initially defined.

Down side: The list can only contain a specific predefined amount of items.

As a single linked list the data structure has to hold a head pointer. This data structure holds a head pointer however in this specific implementation it is a int. The head of the list is the pointer that holds the index to the first node. The first node holds the index to the next node and so on. The last node in the list will hold a next value of -1. This will indicate the end of the list. The fact that indices are taken as elements are added into the structure makes a requirement for a free list head. This free list is incorporated into the same 2-dementional array. Just as the head is an int the free list pointer is an int.

[image]

Now the data structure is composted of 3 major elements. The head pointer, the free head pointer and the 2-dimentional array. The list has to be initialized correctly to allow the list to be used. The list should be initialized as below.

[image]

Reference is this [link](http://www.brokendust.com/Articles/ArrayBasedLinkedList.htm)